# could not use the full range of double in C#?

Tags: c#, double

I could not use the full range of double data type with precession.

My requirement is,
I need to increment precession of double data type range within its range.
e.g.

double number = 12345678912345678.0;

number = number + 0.00001;

I expect number should be 12345678912345678.00001, but actual result is 12345678912345678.0.

In the snap attached I have a 17 digit ,14 digit and 12 digit keys, 
For each key I am incrementing some precession number say 0.00001.
But this operation did not incrementing the precession for 17 and 14 digit keys .so that I am in trouble using these values in SortedList which does not allow duplicates.

[image: example code and out put snap]

Comment: because double precision is 15-16 digits. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx

Comment: Indeed. Look at [decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) instead.

Comment: The word is 'precision'.

Comment: There will be a point where you can't even add 1.0 to a double